# SQL Server Transpose (maybe pivot?) multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose, unpivot

My situation is this:

I have a survey with 400 users (rows) answering 76 questions (columns). These users already have an ID in the database. I've created a table that contains the questions per company and each question has its own ID. So now I need to marry the question ID to the answer per User ID.

When I import, the column headers need to be:

```
User ID   |  Question ID  |  Answer
xxxxxxx   | xxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx
```

Instead of:

```
User ID  |  Question ID 1 | Question ID 2 | Question ID 3 | etc...
xxxxxx   | xxxxx          | xxxxx         | xxxxx         | ...
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: have you tried writing it as a pivot query yet?

Comment: You mention importing the answers; have you already done that?  If not, why not transpose the data before loading into the database.  It's easy to do with something like Excel.

Comment: Up til this point, that's what I've been doing but there are so many users it would take me forever to assign the user ID's back to the answers. I've been looking for a way to do this via pivot tables but can't get around removing the hierarchy structure yet.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to UNPIVOT the data.  There are several ways that this can be done depending on your version of SQL Server.

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you can use the UNPIVOT function which converts the columns to rows:

```
select userid, questionid, answer
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  answer
  for questionId in (QuestionId1, QuestionId2)
) unpiv;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use the UNPIVOT function but you can also use CROSS APPLY and VALUES to transform the data from columns to rows:

```
select t.userid, c.questionid, c.answer
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('QuestionId1', QuestionId1),
    ('QuestionId2', QuestionId2),
    ...
) c (questionId, answer);
```

Then if you have an unknown number of columns that you need to convert to rows, then you could use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name != 'userid'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select userid, questionid, answer
     from yourtable
     unpivot
     (
        answer
        for questionid in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec(@query);
```

As a side note when you are performing this type of conversion the data of the columns being converted to rows, must be the same datatype.  For example if Question1 and Question2 were different datatypes, then you would need to convert them prior to the unpivot similar to this:

```
select userid, questionid, answer
from
(
  select userid, 
    cast(questionid1 as varchar(10)) questionid1,
    cast(questionid2 as varchar(10)) questionid2
  from yourtable
) src
unpivot
(
  answer
  for questionId in (QuestionId1, QuestionId2)
) unpiv;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpivot in MSSQL 2005 or higher:

```
SELECT [User ID], [Question ID], [Question Reponse]
FROM 
   (SELECT [User ID], [Question 1], [Question 2]
   FROM pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   ([Question Reponse] FOR [Question ID] IN 
      ([Question 1], [Question 2])
)AS unpvt;
```

From:
 [User ID] int
,[Question 1] VARCHAR(100)
,[Question 2] VARCHAR(100)

Results:

```
| USER ID | QUESTION ID | QUESTION REPONSE |
--------------------------------------------
|       1 |  Question 1 |             Blah |
|       1 |  Question 2 |         BlahBlah |
|       2 |  Question 1 |         MoreBlah |
|       3 |  Question 1 |      No Response |
|       3 |  Question 2 |             Else |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab643/1)